# discord.py error: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hello World i just started working on a discord bot.

My bot can answer and send gifs, so my next step is to embed gifs.

Repl says:
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Any Help would be apprechiated!

Here is my code:

> Sorry if its very basic ;-;

Code:

```
@client.command(hug)
async def reyhugs(ctx):
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title=":x: rey hugs @user",
                color=discord.Colour.purple()
            )
            embed.set_image(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/821733999637561385/843251675275591720/steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net.gif")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: check if you are mixing tabs and spaces or simply have a space too few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

and the way that you did write the code is wrong
correct it and it will work

```
@client.command()
async def reyhugs(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f":x: rey hugs {ctx.author.mention}", description="_ _",color=discord.Colour.purple())
    embed.set_image(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/821733999637561385/843251675275591720/steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net.gif")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: thank you i'll try to look for these little problems ^^ <3

Answer (score 2):

Your error message says it all. Your indention-levels don't match. As Python is an interpreter language, this is something you really need to look out for!

```
@client.command(hug)
async def reyhugs(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=":x: rey hugs @user",
        color=discord.Colour.purple()
    )
    embed.set_image(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/821733999637561385/843251675275591720/steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net.gif")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```